# sftp into chroot works fine, but debug messages reveil non-chroot authorized_keys absolute path

Tags: sftp, chroot, sshd

I have configured per-user chroot environments for SFTP to go into /somedir/jail/$user:

snippet from my /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Match User myname
   AllowTcpForwarding no
   X11Forwarding no
   ChrootDirectory /somedir/jail/myname
   AuthorizedKeysFile /somedir/jail/myname/home/myname/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This works fine:

```
% sftp myname@myserver
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /home/myname
```

However, when I add the debug options to the "sftp" command, the remote sshd reveils full path info of the "authorized_keys" files, which is not what we want to let discovered:

```
% sftp -v myname@myserver
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
...
debug1: Remote: /somedir/jail/myname/home/myname/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
...
```

Is there any way that the SSHD can be configured to not show this information, or no debug messages at all even though the client SFTP requested it with the "-v" options ?